# How to fx this code to make the minimum height for the div to be 660px?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am not that a savvy JS developer and I need to fix the below code to make sure the div minimum height is 660px, can someone tell me what do I need to change/add?

```
<script>
  $(window).load(function(){
    var innerContainerWidth = $('#content').width();

    var innerContainerHeight = $('#content').height();

    var outerContainerWidth = $('#main').width();

    var sidebar = ((outerContainerWidth - innerContainerWidth)/2)-30;

    var rightBarHeight = $("#right-bar").outerHeight(true);

    if(innerContainerHeight < rightBarHeight){
        $('#content').css( "min-height", rightBarHeight );
    }

    $("#right-bar").css("width", sidebar);
    $("#left-bar").css("width", sidebar);

    $("#left-bar").stickyfloat({duration:0});
    $("#right-bar").stickyfloat({duration:0});

  });
  $(window).resize(function() {
      var innerContainerWidth = $('#content').width();
      var outerContainerWidths = $('#main').width();
      var innerContainerHeight = $('#content').height();
      var rightBarHeight = $("#right-bar").outerHeight(true);
      var sidebarWidth = ((outerContainerWidths - innerContainerWidth)/2)-30;

      if(innerContainerHeight < rightBarHeight){
        $('#content').css( "min-height", rightBarHeight );
      }
      $("#right-bar").css("width", sidebarWidth);

      $("#left-bar").css("width", sidebarWidth);

    });
</script>
```

Comment: There are many possible divs involved ... Which one is concerned ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use min-height in your css class

```
.cssClass{
    min-height:660px;
}
```